# fs.writeFile and fs.openSync bad file descriptor error

Tags: node.js

I'm using this function and get this error

```
{ Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
    at Error (native) errno: -4083, code: 'EBADF', syscall: 'write' }
```

Function:

```
saveMap: function(body) {
    var fd = fs.openSync("C:/mypath", 'w');
    fs.writeFile(fd, body, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 
    fs.closeSync(fd);
},
```

I'm using fd so it can create the file if it doesn't exist. (I've tested with just writeFile on an existing file and it worked).

It's probably something obvious apologize for the noob question.

Comment: Put the `fs.closeSync(fd)` into the callback :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Windows Defender was restricting nodejs from accessing files since my whole drive was under the controlled folder access list of Windows Defender and the file/module nodejs was trying to access was in that drive only.